# добавление контактов в Telegram

Tags: python, telegram

как-то можно сделать скрипт,который будет добавлять номера телефонов из excel или другого формата,в контакты,в последующем добавлять их в конфу в телеграме.

Comment: да, можно, с помощью `telethon`

Comment: не подскажешь как именно,читал документацию,что-то не нашел насчет этого инфу(

Comment: https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/import_contacts.html#examples

Answer (score 0):

Код из документации https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/contacts/import_contacts.html#examples

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.contacts.ImportContactsRequest(
        contacts=[types.InputPhoneContact(
            client_id=random.randrange(-2**63, 2**63),
            phone='some string here',
            first_name='some string here',
            last_name='some string here'
        )]
    ))
    print(result.stringify())
```